# How to add a pause at end of a gnuplot gif animate sequence

Tags: gnuplot, animated-gif

I generate a gif animation sequence with `gif animate` terminal, but i want to add a pause at the end of the sequence such that the last frame show for a longer time.

Is that possible? How? 
thanks.

[My gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFcqY.gif)

Comment: There is no option for the gif terminal for this. You'll need to do that manually by repeating the last plot several times.

Comment: ok. thanks. In fact, that isn't too hard.